# Error: Call to a member function contains() on array Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3

I'm trying to check if list of entity contains an entity but it gives me the following error :

```
Error: Call to a member function contains() on array
```

This is my function code :

```
 public function findAllEquivalents($reference)
{
    $equivalents =  $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p FROM EKPlateformeBundle:Piece p where p.reference = 
            :ref')
        ->setParameter('ref',$reference)
        ->getResult();

    $listFinal = $equivalents ; 
    foreach ($equivalents as $piece)
    {
        $autreEquivalents = $piece->getEquivalents();
        foreach ($autreEquivalents as $p)
        {
            if (!$listFinal->contains($p)) //  error here 
            {
               $listFinal->add($p);
            } 
        }
    }       
    return $listFinal ; 
}
```

I am using Symfony 3.3.2 and doctrine2.
Thanks.

Comment: PHP arrays are not objects. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php

Comment: Thanks . it works , I changed contains with in_array and add with array_push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited : Correct code

```
  public function findAllEquivalents($reference)
{
    $equivalents =  $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p FROM EKPlateformeBundle:Piece p where p.reference = :ref')
        ->setParameter('ref',$reference)
        ->getResult();

    $listFinal = $equivalents ; 
    //array_push($listFinal, $listFinal);

    foreach ($equivalents as $piece)
    {
        $autreEquivalents = $piece->getEquivalents();
        foreach ($autreEquivalents as $p)
        {
            if (!in_array($p, $listFinal))
            //if (!$listFinal->contains($p))
            {
                array_push($listFinal, $p);          
            } 
        }
    }       
    return $listFinal ; 
}
```